# How to boot from my old ssd

Tags: boot, menu, macosx

i wanted to try ubuntu, and made a bootable Memory stick and the ubuntu installer and try ubuntu works just fine. But now ubuntu or something overrides my macs boot menu and I do not know how to get back to my mac os.

Comment: Try running `sudo update-grub` from a terminal in Ubuntu and then reboot. You may have to hold down the Shift key for GRUB's menu to appear.

Answer (score 1):

When your Mac boots up, hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key. This will enter the Mac's BIOS boot menu and you can choose your `Macintosh HD` from here.

EDIT:
Try this instead:
Open a terminal in Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`. Hopefully, this will add Mac OS to your GRUB menu and you'll be able to boot. If it doesn't, you most liekly chose to erase your disk and install Ubuntu, which means OS X is gone.

Comment: No it doesnt work, the mac bootup sound does not plays either. It just skips right to the ubuntu install

Comment: You pressed the `option` key right as the computer turns on?

Comment: Yes, starting macosx in safe mode does not work either

Comment: OK. I'll edit my answer with a new option.

Comment: Can I install mac os after installing ubuntu again?

Comment: When I type the command, this error message pops up, failed to get canonical path of /cow

Comment: Try running `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` to reinstall GRUB.

Comment: Yeah, but can i reformat the disc and install mac osx afterwards?

Comment: When i tried running the code it said could not find device for /boot: not found or not a bloxk device